# How to update the status on a Jira issue vis Jira Rest Api

Tags: jira-rest-api

I want to change the status of the project issue on Jira. The status is **Open** and I want to make it **Fixed**. My url is PUT https://jiradbg-sandbox.deutsche-boerse.de/rest/api/latest/issue/PID-XX

```
{
    "update": {
        "fields":{
            "status": [
                {
                    "set": "Fixed"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and the response is:

```
{
    "errorMessages": ["Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5de98556; line: 3, column: 9] 
(through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean[\"update\"])"]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems that you are encountering here.

The first problem is `update` or `fields` should be provided separately to Jira's edit issue API, not one inside of the other. They have equivalent functionality so normally only one is used. For example to update the summary field provide either `update`:

```
{
  "update": {
    "summary": [
      {
        "set": "Updated by update"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or `fields`:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "Summary set by fields"
  }
}
```

However the status field is a special case and can't be updated directly, which is the second problem here. Changing a status in Jira is called a transition. You need to trigger the transition to move the issue into the status you want.

Start by identifying the available transitions by calling the [get transitions API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getTransitions):

```
GET https://example.net/rest/api/latest/issue/PID-XX/transitions
```

This tells you which transitions are currently available, something like this:

```
{
  "expand": "transitions",
  "transitions": [
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Fixed",
      "to": {
        "self": "https://example.net/rest/api/2/status/10001",
        "description": "",
        "iconUrl": "https://example.net/images/icons/status_generic.gif",
        "name": "Fixed",
        "id": "10001",
        "statusCategory": {
          "self": "https://example.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3",
          "id": 3,
          "key": "done",
          "colorName": "green",
          "name": "Done"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Take the `id` of the transition you want, in this case 21, then post it to the [issue transition API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-doTransition):

```
POST https://example.net/rest/api/latest/issue/PID-XX/transitions
```

Use a request body like this:

```
{
  "transition": {
    "id": 21
  }
}
```

You should get a 204 HTTP response from Jira which indicates the transition was successful.

Comment: I have this result from my GET `{ "expand": "transitions", "transitions": [{"id": "11", "name": "Analysis started", "to": { } },{"id": "321","name": "Reject", "to": {} }]}`

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask regarding this response that I am receiving : `" customfield_10874": "string expected at index 0"` 

Does anyone how can I fix this also? Thank you all very much.

Comment: @RenosBardhis The `"customfield_10874": "string expected at index 0"` suggests that this custom field is a required field; there may be a validator set on the transition which requires that the field `customfield_10874` has been filled in. You should ensure that it has been set before you transition the issue, or set it yourself by calling the edit issue API with either `update` or `fields` with the value for that custom field.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested. I did the update of the Jira issue. But, I have this issue also: ```Field with id' customfield_10874' and name 'Linked Defects' does not support operation 'fields' Supported operation(s) are: 'add ,set, remove'```